# Stepper with pure javascript - previous function not working

Tags: javascript

How to make it return to false once exceeded max step (which is the last step), previous function not working once exceeded max step, I tried to set current step as -1 but still doesn't work.

I get this error msg (*TypeError: bullets[current] is undefined*) on my console when it exceeded max step.

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```js
const bullets=[...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];

const max=4;
let current=-1;

function next(){
 current+=1;
 if(!bullets[current]){
  return false; 
 }
 
 bullets[current].classList.add('hovered');
}

function previous(){
 bullets[current].classList.remove('hovered');
 current-=1;
 if(!bullets[current]){
  return false; 
 }
 
 bullets[current].classList.add('hovered');
}
```

```css
.progressbar{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
 align-items:flex-end;
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}
.item{
 text-align:center;
 width:20%;
 position:relative;
}
.text{
 height:50px;
 margin:10px 0px;
 color:#3CB371;
}
.bullet{
 border:1px solid #3CB371;
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 color:#3CB371;
 display:inline-block;
 transition:background-color 500ms;
 line-height:20px;
}
.bullet.hovered{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#3CB371;
 bottom:10px;
}
.bullet.completed:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 bottom:80px;
 height:1px;
 width:calc(133% - 21px);
 background-color:#3CB371;
 margin-left:7px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet completed">1</div>
  <div class="text">Hello Hello Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet completed">2</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet completed">3</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item completed">
  <div class="bullet">4</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div onclick="previous();">Previous</div>
<div onclick="next();">Next</div>
```

Comment: Accessing a non-existent index in an array will give you `undefined`, not `null` - so, test against `undefined` instead of `null`

Comment: I changed it to undefined but still not working. It wouldn't stop at last step.

Comment: You would just use `if(!bullets[current])`

Comment: Updated my snippet. Why is it still not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unconditionally incrementing/decrementing `current` at the moment. Even if you don't try changing the `classList` on *this* call of `next` or `previous`, the next time either button is clicked, the `current` index may not exist. So, in `previous`, when you do `bullets[current].classList.remove('hovered');` at the beginning of the function, that will throw if the last `current` went beyond the possible indicies for the `bullets` collection.

Consider using `Math.max` / `Math.min` to ensure that `current` is constrained to the possible indicies (or `-1`, in the case that nothing should be highlighted):

```js
const bullets = [...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];

let current = -1;

function next() {
  current = Math.min(current + 1, bullets.length - 1);
  bullets[current].classList.add('hovered');
}

function previous() {
  if (bullets[current]) {
    bullets[current].classList.remove('hovered');
  }
  current = Math.max(current - 1, -1);
}
```

```css
.progressbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  color: #3CB371;
}

.bullet {
  border: 1px solid #3CB371;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #3CB371;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 500ms;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.bullet.hovered {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3CB371;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.bullet.completed:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 80px;
  height: 1px;
  width: calc(133% - 21px);
  background-color: #3CB371;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bullet completed">1</div>
    <div class="text">Hello Hello Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bullet completed">2</div>
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bullet completed">3</div>
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item completed">
    <div class="bullet">4</div>
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div onclick="previous();">Previous</div>
<div onclick="next();">Next</div>
```

Comment: thanks! you just saved my day! :D have a great day ahead!

Comment: is it possible to go from first step to third step and highlight skipped step?